# Which ASP.NET class has the Session_End event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have been using ASP since classic ASP, i.e. ASP 3.0.

And during my ASP.NET 1.1 days, I remember reading one of the Wrox books in which it said that the `Global.asax` (from our earlier `Global.asa`) would still honor any method you named `Session_Start` and `Session_End` and `Application_Start` and so on, even though `events` in .NET were not to be written *just like this*, in that they had a proper syntax and it was necessary to learn delegates and all.

And the book also mentioned that this short-hand of honoring the old `Global.asa` way was a Visual Studio thing only. Visual Studio internally re-wired this short-hand and wrote the missing syntax someplace else to wire up the actually delegate instances with our funnily named event handling methods.

Anyway, so my question is two-fold:

1. On which class exactly may I find the `Session_End` (surely, the event is called something else) event? I looked up [`System.Web.HttpApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.8) but there isn't any such event as `SessionEnd` or even anything of a name that might likely designate such an event.

   And it isn't (obviously as its name suggests it to be merely a state-holder property bag) on the [`HttpSessionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate?view=netframework-4.8) object either.
2. Where can I find that write-up online that tells us that all of this jiggery-pokery is actually a Visual Studio thing. That is, if you were to write an ASP.NET application in Notepad (or anywhere outside of Visual Studio), you'd better have to behave and wire up the delegate instances properly, and that the `Session_End` moniker just wouldn't cut it for the ASP.NET runtime.

BTW, I am using .NET Framework version 4.6.1.

Comment: You probably looking for session module and its events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule?view=netframework-4.8... Note that there is genreally Session_End event  does not exist for non in-memory sessions - so you can safely ignore it existance for production usage.

Comment: The event wiring is not VS specific as VS doesn't have its own compiler. The wiring mechanism, done by the ASP.NET runtime, is perfectly explained in this [Rick's Strahl blog entry](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work).